# Redirecting a command to an .exe causing a repeat in the command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have an exe program that uses a command line GUI and would like to set up a batch script to run a few commands automatically, so here are the sort of commands that the GUI uses:

```
?   = help
s   = start
l   = status
r   = reset
x   = exit
```

I would like to create a batch file that automatically runs the start command I have tried a few things to no avail such as the below.

### using a cannedreponsesfile as the input:

```
@echo off
START /b <path>\service.exe < <path>\cannedreponses.txt
```

And I receive the following error:
    The system cannot find the path specified.
The path referenced in the batch script seems to be ok I checked with dir /s /b

I have also attempted this command
    `echo s |START /b service.exe`

This seems to have better results, but it seems to keep repeating input. 
Any idea what is going on, or how I can do this in a batch file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you menad with "repeating input"? how does this relate to the path not found error mentioned earlier? anyway, if yu have a problem with a path, it is unwise to replace it with "<path>" in your question. also, the redirection of the cannedresponses will go to "start", not to "service.exe"

Comment: There is a second command that did not indent correctly. _echo s |START /b service.exe_ this pipes the 's' character to the service, but the command seems to keep throwing characters to the pipe, and so the start service, or the status is constantly being entered for stdin. From what I see I don't have a problem with the path, please see below. The path is simple, no special charcters except for '_'. I have checked this by using a **dir /s /b **. Also, thanks for replying to the first comment, i didn't know it would be redirected to the START and not the service.exe.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have overcensored your question.

In all probability, the problem is with `<path>`

If the real string you are using contains separators (especially spaces) or some other special characters, then you need `"enclose the string in quotes"`.

There's a quirk with `start` however - the very first string quoted encountred is interpreted as a "window title" so you may need to use

```
start /b "" "whatever 1" "whatever 2"
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be the caveat of special characters that you describe here. I have a simple path that is like C:\Software\<servicename>.exe the service name also has no special characters. Also to make sure I tried quotes around the service name (with empty title quotes also) and the piped input to no avail, i still keep receiving the same error, as in **The system cannot find the file specified.**

Answer (score 0):

The start is unnecessary here and only introduces a source for errors. Just say

```
Echo s|service.exe
```

Comment: I have tried this:  
echo s | Service.exe  
Service <v.2.15>  

Service listen port = xxxx
Service Started

?   = help  
s   = start  
l   = status  
r   = reset  
x   = exit  

Service listen port = xxxx  
Service Started  

?   = help  
s   = start  
l   = status  
r   = reset  
x   = exit  
  
Service listen port = xxxx  
Service Started  

?   = help  
s   = start  
l   = status  
r   = reset  
x   = exit  
  
This continues until i press Ctrl+Brk.